# $(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_x \simeq \mathbb{C}[x]_x$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> I have to prove that there is an isomorphism $(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy))_x \simeq \mathbb{C}[x]_x$.

Geometrically the situation is clear because we have that $Spec(S^{-1}A)$ is the set of prime ideals that don't contain $f$ (points such that $f$ doesn't vanish), where $S=\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$. So on the left $f=x$ and $x$ doesn't vanish over the $x$-axis minus $[(x)]$. So we have ideals $(x-a,y)$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}^*$. On the right we have that $Spec(\mathbb{C}[x]_x)=\{(0), (x-a)\}$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}^*$. So we have the $x$-axis minus the origin. But how can I prove that there is an isomorphism as rings?

Comment: $Spec(\mathbb{C}[x]_x)$ is not what you say, it is $\{(0), (x)\}$.

Comment: @atricolf Are you confusing $\mathbb C[x]_{(x)}$, which has spectrum $\{(0), (x)\}$ with $\mathbb C[x]_x$ (note that in this ring $x$ is invertible, hence $(x) = \mathbb C[x]_x$).

Comment: @martini You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you invert $x$ and kill $xy$, you kill $y$. Hence, $k[x,y]/(xy)_x = k[x,y]/(y)_x = k[x]_x$.